# Profiling Templated Library C++

Tags: c++, templates, profiling, valgrind, massif

I am including a huge template library in my `main.cpp` file, I want to heap profile the resulting program. I am using `massif` for that with `ms_print` for visualisation. Compiling with `-pg`.

In the table for detailed snapshots, I would like to see which parts of the code allocate the most memory. The problem is that the information in the table always only refers to `main`, w/out line numbers, sometimes even "???".

I realize that all of the templates are included in `main.cpp`, i.e., main is de facto compiled from one enormous source file, with no chance of distinguishing between what line in which `.tcc` file the call stems from.

Is there a solution to this problem or a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your program compiled with debug symbols? That might be step 1.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just tried it and it solved the problem. I thought -pg would suffice, stupid. Thanks.